# Protecting security tokens from disassembly

Tags: c#, .net, security

I'm in the process of developing a set of web services for a project involving both web and desktop/mobile apps. I'm grouping them like that because of a security-related issue.

When distributing desktop or mobile software, I'm basically sending the software to my users. A non obfuscated .NET assembly's code can be read easily, and I've come to realize that obfuscation techniques or native packing can only go that far when it comes to protecting your software's privacy and integrity. Even native software compiled from a C source may be decompiled clearly enough to hack it. While I'm aware that the bulk of the security concerns should be dealt with on the webservice side, I have a hard time figuring out how to prevent unauthorized access when people have a working tool to access my service.

While this is not my only concern, I'll focus this question on a specific case.

Suppose I issue API keys for my services. I have no plans to offer third-party access to the services, but the keys are meant to identify and authenticate/authorize my applications. One way or another, I will need to deploy the API key on the user's machine, be it an hardcoded and obfuscated string, or an encrypted file, or whatever. Once it's on the user machine, I expect that there will always be some people that are skilled enough to break any protection layer I may add (supposing they are sufficiently motivated, of course :) ). Sooner or later, they will find out that API key, and then anybody will be able to access my services as if they were my apps themselves.

**What is a secure way to enforce authentication/authorization of software that resides on the client side?** I'm thinking mainly about C#/.NET, but I'm open to any general technique in any programming language.

Comment: As you pointed out yourself, once a hacker has access to the client hardware you have lost. There are limited ways to mitigate this, mostly by the OS (Windows), do not DIY this. The best answer is to keep everything important on the servers.

Comment: @HenkHolterman How would I do that? What are the techniques that don't require the client to know a secret token - or a "secret" algorithm, at that?

Comment: In the end you really can't. In a browser (anonymous client), we use user/password over https. On a phone you may have some DeviceId/AppId support. Physical ownership of the Phone (and its password) is your credential. When the phone is reported lost, the server revokes that Id.

Comment: In the end, should my webservice just expect to be contacted by anybody? Does it really have no (sensibly) secure way to make sure that it is my app that is calling, and not a hacked client?

Comment: Other than magic? No.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for some kind of two-factor authentication (so having a "just API key" is not enough for proven authentication).
You can use, for instance:

- Social networks for the OAuth workflow
- SMS to a phone number associated with given user
- Hardware tokens like "RSA SecurID" https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SecurID

And, as usual: efforts to crack your software could cost more than a legit end-user price.

Comment: I think your solution only applies to user authentication, while I refer to app authentication. Also, even in case of a SecurID-like, TOTP-based mechanism, how would I protect the shared secret token from reverse engineering?

Comment: User auth _is_ App auth with some added user input.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True that. But at least a user may know his password and not share it with anyone: on the other hand, the bytes I send to my users are not able to keep a secret to themselves :)